# Joining multiple thread results using callback method

Tags: java, multithreading, callback

How we can use callback method in java to join the result of multiple threads which are processed in parallel?

Comment: Use `Future` interface.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [CompletionService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionService.html). It receive [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) results in a queue as they become available from the executor threads. It is not technically a callback but acts like one. For example:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        CompletionService<SomeResult> completionService = 
           new ExecutorCompletionService<SomeResult>(executor);

        ResultProcessor processor = new ResultProcessor(completionService);
        processor.start();

        completionService.submit(new Callable<SomeResult>() {
           public SomeResult call() {
               ...
               return result;
           }
        });
    }
}

class SomeResult {}

class ResultProcessor extends Thread {
   private CompletionService<SomeResult> completionService;

   ResultProcessor(CompletionService completionService) {
       this.completionService = completionService;
   }

   public void run() {
      while(...) {
          Future<SomeResult> resultFuture = completionService.take(); //blocks if none available
          SomeResult result = resultFuture.get();
          ... // result processing
      }
   }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not using callbacks, but Java's [fork/join](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html) framework would be a good way to start, it's exactly meant for synchronizing on parallel executing tasks.

But if you want to build something 'callback based' you would pass an interface to the threads that is executed once they are finished that will do the synchronization and make sure the code is thread-safe.

Comment: Actually I explained fork join framework, but interviewer was interested in callback method to do so, that's what puzzled me how we can do this.

Answer (score 0):

you can call a `synchronized` method to 'join' result in each individual thread, and you can use a barrier or a countdownlatch to synchronize those threads.

Answer (score 0):

With fork/join, the main thread waits until all threads/forks to finish, then process all the results;  with callback, each thread calls a method in the main thread to publish its result once the result is ready. So callback may be slightly faster when threads' execution time aren't equal.